# Вывод фото в интернет-магазин php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo

Всем привет)
Я делаю проект для зачета в университете, мне нужно, чтобы выводилось то изображение, IDtovar у которого совпадает с ID у таблицы photo, я понимаю как это должно работать, но никак не могу это воплотить в жизнь.

Вставить нужно, где img1 ()

Спасибо)
[image: Скрин связей с бд]
[image: Скрин интернет-магазина]

```
div class="tovari"> 
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['nomer'])) {
            $nomer = $_GET['nomer'];
            $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT ID, tcena, nazvanieTovara FROM Tovar WHERE `Tovar`.`IDstrani` = $nomer");
            $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
        <div class="tovar">
            <h1 class="blok">
                <div class="img1"><img src="" height="115px" width="115px" ></div>
                <p id="nazvanie"><?=$row['nazvanieTovara']?></p> 
            </h1>
            <p id="tcena"><?=$row['tcena'] ?> руб.</p>
            <div class="add">
            <input type="image" src="img/add.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }}
            ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: fetch() два раза не делают, первый раз ты извлек данные из стейтмента, а потом перезатёр их новым фетчем, предполагаю в запросе должно было прийти всего 1 значение из БД

Comment: картинка пустая, потому что данные о картинке хранятся в другой таблице, надо делать INNER JOIN чтобы извлечь данные  картинки - `SELECT * FROM Tovar INNER JOIN Photo ON Tovar.ID=Photo.IDtovar WHERE Tovar.IDstrani = $nomer`

Comment: в примере 2 как раз примеры работы fetch() https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch